# How could I generate words starting with P,h,D?

Tags: random, curated-data

A friend of mine is a PhD candidate and posted a picture on Facebook with funny words starting with 'p', 'h' and 'd' like "Please hire. Desperate" or "Permanent head Damage". I thought I could try and programmatically generate some word combinations with Mathematica.

Here is my version. Most of the results are meaningless, but occasionally a good combination will show up like "panegyric happiness date".

1. Could it be improved (i.e. increase its signal/noise ratio)?
2. Could the following construct be condensed `{"." -> "", ";" -> "", "," -> "", ... -> ""`? Schematically: `{".", ";", ","} - >""`
3. The reason I used `StringMatchQ` with `Map[]` is because I didn't know how to group the results based on the first letter of the words, e.g. {please, hire, permanent, damage, head, desperate} -> {{please, permanent}, {hire, head}, {damage, desperate}}`.

Also, I used words from `DictionaryLookup[]`, picking those with the most meanings (to increase the likelihood of a meaningful combination), but the results were worse.

Here is my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

allWords = 
  ExampleData[{"Text", "PrideAndPrejudice"}, "Words"] // DeleteDuplicates;

phdWords = Pick[
     allWords,
     StringMatchQ[allWords, #]] & /@ {"p" ~~ __, "h" ~~ __, "d" ~~ __};

phdWords =
  StringReplace[#,
     {"." -> "", ";" -> "", "," -> "", "!" -> "", "?" -> "", 
      "\"" -> ""}] & /@ phdWords;

filterWordsByPart[wordList_, part_] :=
  Select[
   wordList,
   MemberQ[
     WordData[#, "PartsOfSpeech"], part] &];

finalWords = MapThread[
   filterWordsByPart,
   {phdWords, {"Adjective", "Noun", "Noun"}}];

Table[
  Flatten@(RandomSample[#, 1] & /@ finalWords),
  {20}] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

And this is a sample output:

[image]

Comment: This also reminds me of a fiendishly clever oneliner from [2011](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/01/the-2011-mathematica-one-liner-competition/) by William Wu.

Comment: actually, `WordData` might just be the thing here, too...

Comment: From the old joke: Piled Higher, Deeper

Comment: When I was in graduate school I worked for a city as a street maintenance worker.  When I told my boss that I was working on a Ph.D., he replied that he had one of those in his truck:  a post hole digger.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To find out what words go well together one can sample some text from `ExampleData` and pick only words that have at least been mention together pairwise before.

```
sample = ToLowerCase@StringJoin[{
    ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}], 
    ExampleData[{"Text", "OnTheNatureOfThingsEnglish"}],
    ExampleData[{"Text", "OriginOfSpecies"}],
    ExampleData[{"Text", "USConstitution"}]}];
words = StringCases[sample, WordCharacter..];

(* All adjacent words {word1, word2} *)
pairs = Partition[words, 2, 2, 1];

phpairs = Pick[pairs,
   Thread[
    StringMatchQ[pairs[[All, 1]], "p" ~~ __, IgnoreCase -> True] &&
    StringMatchQ[pairs[[All, 2]], "h" ~~ __, IgnoreCase -> True]]];

hdpairs = Pick[pairs,
   Thread[
    StringMatchQ[pairs[[All, 1]], "h" ~~ __, IgnoreCase -> True] &&
    StringMatchQ[pairs[[All, 2]], "d" ~~ __, IgnoreCase -> True]]];

(* Filter out {"p","h"} pairs that have no corresponding {"h","d"} *)
phpairs = Select[phpairs, MemberQ[hdpairs[[All, 1]], #[[2]]] &];
```

After that initialization run this a few times:

```
(* Too many boring ones with had/has/have *)
ph = RandomChoice[Cases[phpairs, {_, Except["had" | "has" | "have"]}]];
hd = RandomChoice@Cases[hdpairs, {Last@ph, _}];
StringJoin[{First@ph, " ", First@hd, " ", Last@hd}]


(* Example results:
 "published how different"
 "person having diverged"
 "perish herself down"
 "pleasure hath dropped"
 "pities his death"
 "plants higher degree" *)
```

Comment: Text can also be taken from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Category:Bookshelf)

Comment: I pulled 30 books at random from PG, capitalization mine: "Permanent happiness? Depends", "Peace hitherto: Despairing", "possible hurt done", "Past hope. Despair", "poor hard duty", "play heavy drinking", "pretty hot discussions", "peasants high degree", "passed having died" I filtered about 50% of the results.

Comment: How come with Mathematica 10.0.1 under OS X I get results with the last word being "and" ? As if `Except[]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

[`DictionaryLookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DictionaryLookup.html) ain´t so bad (I like "Paleozoic haircuts difficulties"):

```
{a, b, c} = DictionaryLookup[# ~~ ___] & /@ {"P", "h", "d"};

Grid[Transpose[RandomChoice[#, 10] & /@ {a, b, c}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As for filtering, what about (directly from [`tutorial/StringPatterns`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html)):

```
StringCases["a6;b23c456;R", LetterCharacter]
```

> ```
> (*{"a", "b", "c", "R"}*)
> ```

or another variety to keep whitespaces:

```
StringReplace["a6 ;b23c:456 , R a", Characters[";,:"] -> ""]
```

> ```
> (*"a6 b23c456  R a"*)
> ```